# tr and rot13 question

Tags: bash, tr

I'm playing Bandit by OverTheWire. On stage 11 they ask you to translate a data file with this plaintext `"Gur cnffjbeq vf 5Gr8L4qetPEsPk8htqjhRK8XSP6x2RHh"`. I know that the solution is to use this command.

```
`tr 'A-Za-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m' <<< "Gur cnffjbeq vf 5Gr8L4qetPEsPk8htqjhRK8XSP6x2RHh"`
```

However, I do not understand why the following options do not work:

```
`tr 'A-Za-z' 'Z-Az-a'`
```

or

```
`tr ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba <<<"Gur cnffjbeq vf 5Gr8L4qetPEsPk8htqjhRK8XSP6x2RHh"`
```

I believe the first example has something to do with tr viewing the range of z-a and Z-A as invalid. why is this?

As for the second example, why does the command output

```
Tfi xmuuqyvj eu 5Ti8O4jvgKVhKp8sgjqsIP8CHK6c2ISs
```

instead of the correct answer:

```
The password is 5Te8Y4drgCRfCx8ugdwuEX8KFC6k2EUu
```

Comment: you seem to have misunderstood rot13. it's not alphabet backwards.

Answer (score 3):

ROT13 shifts the alphabet by 13 positions, such that A and N swap positions, as do B and O, and so forth. It does not reverse the alphabet, which is what your attempts are doing.

The `tr` syntax might be obfuscating this action slightly. The ROT13 encoder/decoder you posted could be written like so to make it a little clearer what’s going on:

```
tr 'A-MN-Za-mn-z' \
   'N-ZA-Mn-za-m' \
<<< ciphertext
```

Here you can see a bit better how corresponding letter ranges relate to each other.

Comment: Your proposal only works in the POSIX locale (US-ASCII) that locale is not in use by the vast majority of people. See my answer...

Comment: @schily, it's only *guaranteed* (by POSIX) to work in the `C` locale. Outside of the C locale, you'll still find it works in most implementations including ones that support multi-byte characters like ast-open's or FreeBSD's. Solaris' /usr/xpg4/bin/tr as mentioned in your answer seems to be an exception.

Comment: See my other comment, this applies at least to Solaris, AIX, HP-UX IRIX, ... and is a result of the collating definitions. If it "works" on FreeBSD, there seems to be extra code to enforce what is expected from the gut.

Answer (score -1):

`tr 'A-MN-Za-mn-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m'` may have worked 50 years ago, but it does not work anymore since 1992, when internationalization has been introduced on UNIX.

Check:

```
$ echo Gur cnffjbeq vf 5Gr8L4qetPEsPk8htqjhRK8XS | /usr/xpg4/bin/tr 'A-MN-Za-mn-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m'
```

outputs (depending on the actual locale) e.g.:

```
vFè pÂÛÛAøßé ÌÛ 5vè8À4éßËEtêEá8VËéAVÈÁ8jÊ
```

Why does this happen?

The reason is that the range `N-Z` contains more than 13 characters, e.g. `Ö`, `Ü`, ... and as a result, when using a `tr` implementation that implements collating correctly, the only way to specify rot13 correctly works using:

```
tr ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm
```

Comment: Note that the behaviour of ranges is unspecified by POSIX outside of the C locale (and `tr 'A-MN-Za-mn-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m'` is required to work as expected in the C locale). That behaviour of Solaris' /usr/xpg4/bin/tr is the odd one out, and it makes range transliterations other than range-to-one useless there.

Comment: You seem to forgot that this is not only th ebehavior on Solaris, but also on AIX and HP-UX. Ranges in a non-POSIX locale are useless, but a result of the definition on collating order. BTW: this has been discussed in dept in ~ 1992 on comp.unix.solaris.